# How to show all photos of an album using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, photo, macos-sierra

I am trying to put together an AppleScript to select each photo in my album.  I have a smart album set up for my wedding and an iphone taking pictures.  As the photos are taken, they are sent via iCloud photo stream to this smart album.  I am using this script to make a slideshow of all the new photos coming in.  (I want it to loop once it gets to the end of the photos.

I tried just making a slideshow, but it doesn't include new photos as they come in.

Here is my script so far.  The error I am getting is that it cannot "Select" the photo.

```
set source_album to "wedding photos"
tell application "Photos"
    activate
    repeat until frontmost
    end repeat

    set photos to media items in album source_album
    set selected_photo to selection
    log selected_photo

    repeat with i from 1 to count (photos)
        set selected_photo to item i of photos
        log selected_photo
        select selected_photo  --ERROR HERE!
        delay 3
    end repeat
end tell
```

Thanks for looking and helping!

Comment: There is no verb named `select` in the `Photos.app` AppleScript dictionary. What are you trying  to do?

Comment: I want to loop through each photo and select that photo, wait 10 seconds, select the next photo, etc etc.  When I reach the end, I want to loop back to the first photo.

Comment: What does "select" mean in this context, and what API construct do you expect it to map to?

Comment: Perhaps verb `start slideshow v : Display an ad-hoc slide show from a list of media items, an album, a folder, or a moment` is what you're looking for; e.g. (untested), `start slideshow using album source_album`.

Comment: All, Thank you for the comments!  I was unable to make it work, so I used a tvOS app called PhotoWall+ that accomplished my use cases.